# Azure authentication popup does not appear in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-msal

I am following
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/quick-start-console-app-csharp
to connect the Microsoft Dataverse environment and invoke the Web API.
I have finished the setup and it is working in the console app.

However, when I switch to the asp.net app with the same C# coding, the authentication popup does not appear. Nothing happened after the below-line runs.

`AuthenticationResult token = await authBuilder.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();`

Are there any settings required when I switch from the console app to the web app for the login popup?